# Is adding documentation refs generally a good thing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, documentation, edits, suggested-edits

[In this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13317614) someone added a link to the documentation.

In my opinion, this adds true value to the answer, but doesn't conflict with the authors opinion. It just shows more sources.

Is this more like an attempt to respond or is it some edit that should be approved?

Comment: This user [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference/879533#879533) [highvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany/959057#959057) answers with link to examples he eddited and now gets +5 when it get upvoted, and I thinkg he has an agenda...

Comment: @AlonEitan this looks like spamming edits - is that okay or abusive? And more general, you think these edits add value?

Comment: I think that it doesn't add value, and somewhat abusive (But i'm not sure). The answers are old and highly upvoted, why one want to improve such old (+6 years ago) and good answers? I think this something a moderator should rule

Comment: @AlonEitan you mentioned +5 when the answer gets upvoted - is this something a 2k+ rep user could do aswell? If yes, this really sounds like something that could easely be abused.

Comment: Take a look on his [reputation log](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5369006/bumbeishvili?tab=reputation) see those `example cited`? This is what happen when you link to a documentation example in SO answer. Now - The questions themselves will attract more users to those examples and will probably upvoted as-well, since that user has contribute to those example, he should also get a +5 on any upvote on that example in the Documentation. So this is something I believe any user seeking for easy reputation will do

Comment: As long as the edits add value who cares if he makes a lot of them... Rep is there so you can earn it, so as long as you are making an actual contribution and not lowering the quality of the doc or answer how could that be abuse?

Comment: @Jacobr365 So do you think we should all go back to old and popular answers, edit and add likes that will give us more reputation? Show I also add to those answers relevant examples from the Documentation that I have edited and will give me extra rep? **If it ain't broke, don't fix it** (And when I say "you", I mean that other guy)

Comment: @AlonEitan If it adds actual value to the answer then yes. And by adding value I am not saying that we should edit answers and add unrelated links. But for me personally, I answer questions when I can, but most of my time on SO is spent browsing and trying to learn more / pick up new tricks. So for me, having a pseudo "Furthing Reading" section would actually be helpful in some cases as long as the refs are on topic. However the review in question is not that helpful, but on more advanced topics I could find this useful.

Comment: @Jacobr365 I think the link should be placed as a comments to the answer, I see this user as a free rider. But I agree that my opinion is as good as yours

Comment: @AlonEitan I would go for the comment idea if comments could be pinned or something. Because not everyone will expand the comment section so a note may go unnoticed. Wish there was a section in answers to add references or something.